# My app runs slower on Android 4 than Android 2

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, loops, versions

I've got an app out for Android that generates sound.

When the CPU is over worked, it doesn't run a tight enough loop and the result is snaps, crackles, and pops in the audio.

I was thinking that with newer devices, there would be less of this.

But it looks like on the tablets and newest phones, where I would expect better hardware and smoother audio, it usually seems to be worse than my old old Droid and Android 2.2.3.

I've got some more testing to do (I usually test this stuff in a Verizon or AT&T store as I can't afford all that hardware myself), but this seems to be the case so far.

What I'm wondering is there anything specific from Android 2 to Android 4 that could account for this?

For example a "governor" that limits how fast a Thread can run.

The loop is running in the run() of a subclass of Thread. It's created in an Activity (as opposed to a Service).

I would post the name and a link to the app (it's free) but I'm afraid that would probably be viewed as spam, or at least improper etiquette.

Comment: Generating sound is not really the kind of app that should overtax even a cheap. slow CPU.  Video maybe, but shovelling values into a D>A audio interface is not CPU-intensive.  Such apps are, (or should be), at the lowest level, 'governed' by the rate at which the sound driver interrupts are raised to reload D>A buffers.  Even the cheapest, nastiest phone CPU should be able to keep up.  Where do you get your audio stream from and how are you feeding it to the driver?  I get the distinct feeling that you are doing something very wrong:(

Comment: I'm generating the sound from user input. Then I write() it to an AudioTrack instance. I don't seem to get any crackles until I have about four of these AudioTracks going, then it only seems to happen when new tracks are made. I can get almost a dozen tracks running smoothly on my Droid, but newer, allegedly more powerful machines seem to dog on it.